# How do I make non-printable template instructions in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, template-design

I'm trying to create a business card template for my work and I wanted to add text to the file giving instructions on how to use the template.

How do I create text that won't print once the file is ready?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new Layer in Indesign via the Layers Panel.

Double-click the new layer and uncheck "Print Layer".

Then place all your instructions on that layer.
To place things on the layer, simply make certain the layer is highlighted in the Layers Panel when you create new elements or paste things.

Comment: And label that layer NONPRINTING INSTRUCTIONS. Just in case. Redundancy can be your friend. I also set text like that in magenta, because nobody ever prints anything in pure magenta, so it's a really obvious visual cue that this is unusual and not part of the design.

Comment: Funny.. I tend to set notes in 100%M as well :)