# Will a non-printable layer in InDesign still export?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, adobe-acrobat

Per a similar question asked, [Can I Put my logo on an outputted PDF?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22206/can-i-put-my-logo-on-an-outputted-pdf), I was familiar with the Acrobat process to create watermarks.  However, I was curious if you created a non-printable layer within InDesign (and we have a question on creating non-printable layers in InDesign, [How do I make non-printable template instructions in InDesign?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15803/how-do-i-make-non-printable-template-instructions-in-indesign)) will that non printable layer still export to a `.pdf` file and will the `.pdf` file in Acrobat preserve the non-printable layer?  I find it hard to test this based on the printer settings but I dont want to test this on a plate maker.  On an Epson printer it appears to work but I am curious to know if anyone has experienced this when plate making or during a burn for a screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set an object in Indesign to non-printing, then export to PDF, the object is not present in the PDF.

It's not hidden or otherwise embedded in the PDF and simply not there.

Non-printing object are truly not there and will not print from the PDF.